# Infinite Swiper in Framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

Is there anyway to build an infinite Swiper (like Tinder) by using this http://framework7.io/docs/swiper.html ?

The idea is to add a new slide when the last slide is "active" but I cant find anyway to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by using append function and appending your content if there is no more slides. Something like infinite scroll but with a little different code.

For example:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 1</span></div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 2</span></div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 3</span></div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide 4</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var html = '';
for (var i = lastIndex + 1; i <= lastIndex + itemsPerLoad; i++) {
  html += '<div class="swiper-slide"><span>Slide '+i+'</span></div>';
} 
// Append new items
$$('.swiper-wrapper').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

The swiper plugin has it's own website with a lot more documentation.

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

You could probably use the `onReachEnd(swiper)` event, and in there add new slides with `mySwiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10"</div>')`

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');

mySwiper.on('onReachEnd', function (swiper) {
    swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">New Slide</div>')
});
```